# Is there a limit for number of rows in CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I found out that when I have many rows in a css grid, it won't go past the 999 items counter.
See the following Example:

I wondered if there is a possibility to show more elements than the 999. Is there any reason why this happens? I can't find any documentation about it!

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
  <div>32</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>35</div>
  <div>36</div>
  <div>37</div>
  <div>38</div>
  <div>39</div>
  <div>40</div>
  <div>41</div>
  <div>42</div>
  <div>43</div>
  <div>44</div>
  <div>45</div>
  <div>46</div>
  <div>47</div>
  <div>48</div>
  <div>49</div>
  <div>50</div>
  <div>51</div>
  <div>52</div>
  <div>53</div>
  <div>54</div>
  <div>55</div>
  <div>56</div>
  <div>57</div>
  <div>58</div>
  <div>59</div>
  <div>60</div>
  <div>61</div>
  <div>62</div>
  <div>63</div>
  <div>64</div>
  <div>65</div>
  <div>66</div>
  <div>67</div>
  <div>68</div>
  <div>69</div>
  <div>70</div>
  <div>71</div>
  <div>72</div>
  <div>73</div>
  <div>74</div>
  <div>75</div>
  <div>76</div>
  <div>77</div>
  <div>78</div>
  <div>79</div>
  <div>80</div>
  <div>81</div>
  <div>82</div>
  <div>83</div>
  <div>84</div>
  <div>85</div>
  <div>86</div>
  <div>87</div>
  <div>88</div>
  <div>89</div>
  <div>90</div>
  <div>91</div>
  <div>92</div>
  <div>93</div>
  <div>94</div>
  <div>95</div>
  <div>96</div>
  <div>97</div>
  <div>98</div>
  <div>99</div>
  <div>100</div>
  <div>101</div>
  <div>102</div>
  <div>103</div>
  <div>104</div>
  <div>105</div>
  <div>106</div>
  <div>107</div>
  <div>108</div>
  <div>109</div>
  <div>110</div>
  <div>111</div>
  <div>112</div>
  <div>113</div>
  <div>114</div>
  <div>115</div>
  <div>116</div>
  <div>117</div>
  <div>118</div>
  <div>119</div>
  <div>120</div>
  <div>121</div>
  <div>122</div>
  <div>123</div>
  <div>124</div>
  <div>125</div>
  <div>126</div>
  <div>127</div>
  <div>128</div>
  <div>129</div>
  <div>130</div>
  <div>131</div>
  <div>132</div>
  <div>133</div>
  <div>134</div>
  <div>135</div>
  <div>136</div>
  <div>137</div>
  <div>138</div>
  <div>139</div>
  <div>140</div>
  <div>141</div>
  <div>142</div>
  <div>143</div>
  <div>144</div>
  <div>145</div>
  <div>146</div>
  <div>147</div>
  <div>148</div>
  <div>149</div>
  <div>150</div>
  <div>151</div>
  <div>152</div>
  <div>153</div>
  <div>154</div>
  <div>155</div>
  <div>156</div>
  <div>157</div>
  <div>158</div>
  <div>159</div>
  <div>160</div>
  <div>161</div>
  <div>162</div>
  <div>163</div>
  <div>164</div>
  <div>165</div>
  <div>166</div>
  <div>167</div>
  <div>168</div>
  <div>169</div>
  <div>170</div>
  <div>171</div>
  <div>172</div>
  <div>173</div>
  <div>174</div>
  <div>175</div>
  <div>176</div>
  <div>177</div>
  <div>178</div>
  <div>179</div>
  <div>180</div>
  <div>181</div>
  <div>182</div>
  <div>183</div>
  <div>184</div>
  <div>185</div>
  <div>186</div>
  <div>187</div>
  <div>188</div>
  <div>189</div>
  <div>190</div>
  <div>191</div>
  <div>192</div>
  <div>193</div>
  <div>194</div>
  <div>195</div>
  <div>196</div>
  <div>197</div>
  <div>198</div>
  <div>199</div>
  <div>200</div>
  <div>201</div>
  <div>202</div>
  <div>203</div>
  <div>204</div>
  <div>205</div>
  <div>206</div>
  <div>207</div>
  <div>208</div>
  <div>209</div>
  <div>210</div>
  <div>211</div>
  <div>212</div>
  <div>213</div>
  <div>214</div>
  <div>215</div>
  <div>216</div>
  <div>217</div>
  <div>218</div>
  <div>219</div>
  <div>220</div>
  <div>221</div>
  <div>222</div>
  <div>223</div>
  <div>224</div>
  <div>225</div>
  <div>226</div>
  <div>227</div>
  <div>228</div>
  <div>229</div>
  <div>230</div>
  <div>231</div>
  <div>232</div>
  <div>233</div>
  <div>234</div>
  <div>235</div>
  <div>236</div>
  <div>237</div>
  <div>238</div>
  <div>239</div>
  <div>240</div>
  <div>241</div>
  <div>242</div>
  <div>243</div>
  <div>244</div>
  <div>245</div>
  <div>246</div>
  <div>247</div>
  <div>248</div>
  <div>249</div>
  <div>250</div>
  <div>251</div>
  <div>252</div>
  <div>253</div>
  <div>254</div>
  <div>255</div>
  <div>256</div>
  <div>257</div>
  <div>258</div>
  <div>259</div>
  <div>260</div>
  <div>261</div>
  <div>262</div>
  <div>263</div>
  <div>264</div>
  <div>265</div>
  <div>266</div>
  <div>267</div>
  <div>268</div>
  <div>269</div>
  <div>270</div>
  <div>271</div>
  <div>272</div>
  <div>273</div>
  <div>274</div>
  <div>275</div>
  <div>276</div>
  <div>277</div>
  <div>278</div>
  <div>279</div>
  <div>280</div>
  <div>281</div>
  <div>282</div>
  <div>283</div>
  <div>284</div>
  <div>285</div>
  <div>286</div>
  <div>287</div>
  <div>288</div>
  <div>289</div>
  <div>290</div>
  <div>291</div>
  <div>292</div>
  <div>293</div>
  <div>294</div>
  <div>295</div>
  <div>296</div>
  <div>297</div>
  <div>298</div>
  <div>299</div>
  <div>300</div>
  <div>301</div>
  <div>302</div>
  <div>303</div>
  <div>304</div>
  <div>305</div>
  <div>306</div>
  <div>307</div>
  <div>308</div>
  <div>309</div>
  <div>310</div>
  <div>311</div>
  <div>312</div>
  <div>313</div>
  <div>314</div>
  <div>315</div>
  <div>316</div>
  <div>317</div>
  <div>318</div>
  <div>319</div>
  <div>320</div>
  <div>321</div>
  <div>322</div>
  <div>323</div>
  <div>324</div>
  <div>325</div>
  <div>326</div>
  <div>327</div>
  <div>328</div>
  <div>329</div>
  <div>330</div>
  <div>331</div>
  <div>332</div>
  <div>333</div>
  <div>334</div>
  <div>335</div>
  <div>336</div>
  <div>337</div>
  <div>338</div>
  <div>339</div>
  <div>340</div>
  <div>341</div>
  <div>342</div>
  <div>343</div>
  <div>344</div>
  <div>345</div>
  <div>346</div>
  <div>347</div>
  <div>348</div>
  <div>349</div>
  <div>350</div>
  <div>351</div>
  <div>352</div>
  <div>353</div>
  <div>354</div>
  <div>355</div>
  <div>356</div>
  <div>357</div>
  <div>358</div>
  <div>359</div>
  <div>360</div>
  <div>361</div>
  <div>362</div>
  <div>363</div>
  <div>364</div>
  <div>365</div>
  <div>366</div>
  <div>367</div>
  <div>368</div>
  <div>369</div>
  <div>370</div>
  <div>371</div>
  <div>372</div>
  <div>373</div>
  <div>374</div>
  <div>375</div>
  <div>376</div>
  <div>377</div>
  <div>378</div>
  <div>379</div>
  <div>380</div>
  <div>381</div>
  <div>382</div>
  <div>383</div>
  <div>384</div>
  <div>385</div>
  <div>386</div>
  <div>387</div>
  <div>388</div>
  <div>389</div>
  <div>390</div>
  <div>391</div>
  <div>392</div>
  <div>393</div>
  <div>394</div>
  <div>395</div>
  <div>396</div>
  <div>397</div>
  <div>398</div>
  <div>399</div>
  <div>400</div>
  <div>401</div>
  <div>402</div>
  <div>403</div>
  <div>404</div>
  <div>405</div>
  <div>406</div>
  <div>407</div>
  <div>408</div>
  <div>409</div>
  <div>410</div>
  <div>411</div>
  <div>412</div>
  <div>413</div>
  <div>414</div>
  <div>415</div>
  <div>416</div>
  <div>417</div>
  <div>418</div>
  <div>419</div>
  <div>420</div>
  <div>421</div>
  <div>422</div>
  <div>423</div>
  <div>424</div>
  <div>425</div>
  <div>426</div>
  <div>427</div>
  <div>428</div>
  <div>429</div>
  <div>430</div>
  <div>431</div>
  <div>432</div>
  <div>433</div>
  <div>434</div>
  <div>435</div>
  <div>436</div>
  <div>437</div>
  <div>438</div>
  <div>439</div>
  <div>440</div>
  <div>441</div>
  <div>442</div>
  <div>443</div>
  <div>444</div>
  <div>445</div>
  <div>446</div>
  <div>447</div>
  <div>448</div>
  <div>449</div>
  <div>450</div>
  <div>451</div>
  <div>452</div>
  <div>453</div>
  <div>454</div>
  <div>455</div>
  <div>456</div>
  <div>457</div>
  <div>458</div>
  <div>459</div>
  <div>460</div>
  <div>461</div>
  <div>462</div>
  <div>463</div>
  <div>464</div>
  <div>465</div>
  <div>466</div>
  <div>467</div>
  <div>468</div>
  <div>469</div>
  <div>470</div>
  <div>471</div>
  <div>472</div>
  <div>473</div>
  <div>474</div>
  <div>475</div>
  <div>476</div>
  <div>477</div>
  <div>478</div>
  <div>479</div>
  <div>480</div>
  <div>481</div>
  <div>482</div>
  <div>483</div>
  <div>484</div>
  <div>485</div>
  <div>486</div>
  <div>487</div>
  <div>488</div>
  <div>489</div>
  <div>490</div>
  <div>491</div>
  <div>492</div>
  <div>493</div>
  <div>494</div>
  <div>495</div>
  <div>496</div>
  <div>497</div>
  <div>498</div>
  <div>499</div>
  <div>500</div>
  <div>501</div>
  <div>502</div>
  <div>503</div>
  <div>504</div>
  <div>505</div>
  <div>506</div>
  <div>507</div>
  <div>508</div>
  <div>509</div>
  <div>510</div>
  <div>511</div>
  <div>512</div>
  <div>513</div>
  <div>514</div>
  <div>515</div>
  <div>516</div>
  <div>517</div>
  <div>518</div>
  <div>519</div>
  <div>520</div>
  <div>521</div>
  <div>522</div>
  <div>523</div>
  <div>524</div>
  <div>525</div>
  <div>526</div>
  <div>527</div>
  <div>528</div>
  <div>529</div>
  <div>530</div>
  <div>531</div>
  <div>532</div>
  <div>533</div>
  <div>534</div>
  <div>535</div>
  <div>536</div>
  <div>537</div>
  <div>538</div>
  <div>539</div>
  <div>540</div>
  <div>541</div>
  <div>542</div>
  <div>543</div>
  <div>544</div>
  <div>545</div>
  <div>546</div>
  <div>547</div>
  <div>548</div>
  <div>549</div>
  <div>550</div>
  <div>551</div>
  <div>552</div>
  <div>553</div>
  <div>554</div>
  <div>555</div>
  <div>556</div>
  <div>557</div>
  <div>558</div>
  <div>559</div>
  <div>560</div>
  <div>561</div>
  <div>562</div>
  <div>563</div>
  <div>564</div>
  <div>565</div>
  <div>566</div>
  <div>567</div>
  <div>568</div>
  <div>569</div>
  <div>570</div>
  <div>571</div>
  <div>572</div>
  <div>573</div>
  <div>574</div>
  <div>575</div>
  <div>576</div>
  <div>577</div>
  <div>578</div>
  <div>579</div>
  <div>580</div>
  <div>581</div>
  <div>582</div>
  <div>583</div>
  <div>584</div>
  <div>585</div>
  <div>586</div>
  <div>587</div>
  <div>588</div>
  <div>589</div>
  <div>590</div>
  <div>591</div>
  <div>592</div>
  <div>593</div>
  <div>594</div>
  <div>595</div>
  <div>596</div>
  <div>597</div>
  <div>598</div>
  <div>599</div>
  <div>600</div>
  <div>601</div>
  <div>602</div>
  <div>603</div>
  <div>604</div>
  <div>605</div>
  <div>606</div>
  <div>607</div>
  <div>608</div>
  <div>609</div>
  <div>610</div>
  <div>611</div>
  <div>612</div>
  <div>613</div>
  <div>614</div>
  <div>615</div>
  <div>616</div>
  <div>617</div>
  <div>618</div>
  <div>619</div>
  <div>620</div>
  <div>621</div>
  <div>622</div>
  <div>623</div>
  <div>624</div>
  <div>625</div>
  <div>626</div>
  <div>627</div>
  <div>628</div>
  <div>629</div>
  <div>630</div>
  <div>631</div>
  <div>632</div>
  <div>633</div>
  <div>634</div>
  <div>635</div>
  <div>636</div>
  <div>637</div>
  <div>638</div>
  <div>639</div>
  <div>640</div>
  <div>641</div>
  <div>642</div>
  <div>643</div>
  <div>644</div>
  <div>645</div>
  <div>646</div>
  <div>647</div>
  <div>648</div>
  <div>649</div>
  <div>650</div>
  <div>651</div>
  <div>652</div>
  <div>653</div>
  <div>654</div>
  <div>655</div>
  <div>656</div>
  <div>657</div>
  <div>658</div>
  <div>659</div>
  <div>660</div>
  <div>661</div>
  <div>662</div>
  <div>663</div>
  <div>664</div>
  <div>665</div>
  <div>666</div>
  <div>667</div>
  <div>668</div>
  <div>669</div>
  <div>670</div>
  <div>671</div>
  <div>672</div>
  <div>673</div>
  <div>674</div>
  <div>675</div>
  <div>676</div>
  <div>677</div>
  <div>678</div>
  <div>679</div>
  <div>680</div>
  <div>681</div>
  <div>682</div>
  <div>683</div>
  <div>684</div>
  <div>685</div>
  <div>686</div>
  <div>687</div>
  <div>688</div>
  <div>689</div>
  <div>690</div>
  <div>691</div>
  <div>692</div>
  <div>693</div>
  <div>694</div>
  <div>695</div>
  <div>696</div>
  <div>697</div>
  <div>698</div>
  <div>699</div>
  <div>700</div>
  <div>701</div>
  <div>702</div>
  <div>703</div>
  <div>704</div>
  <div>705</div>
  <div>706</div>
  <div>707</div>
  <div>708</div>
  <div>709</div>
  <div>710</div>
  <div>711</div>
  <div>712</div>
  <div>713</div>
  <div>714</div>
  <div>715</div>
  <div>716</div>
  <div>717</div>
  <div>718</div>
  <div>719</div>
  <div>720</div>
  <div>721</div>
  <div>722</div>
  <div>723</div>
  <div>724</div>
  <div>725</div>
  <div>726</div>
  <div>727</div>
  <div>728</div>
  <div>729</div>
  <div>730</div>
  <div>731</div>
  <div>732</div>
  <div>733</div>
  <div>734</div>
  <div>735</div>
  <div>736</div>
  <div>737</div>
  <div>738</div>
  <div>739</div>
  <div>740</div>
  <div>741</div>
  <div>742</div>
  <div>743</div>
  <div>744</div>
  <div>745</div>
  <div>746</div>
  <div>747</div>
  <div>748</div>
  <div>749</div>
  <div>750</div>
  <div>751</div>
  <div>752</div>
  <div>753</div>
  <div>754</div>
  <div>755</div>
  <div>756</div>
  <div>757</div>
  <div>758</div>
  <div>759</div>
  <div>760</div>
  <div>761</div>
  <div>762</div>
  <div>763</div>
  <div>764</div>
  <div>765</div>
  <div>766</div>
  <div>767</div>
  <div>768</div>
  <div>769</div>
  <div>770</div>
  <div>771</div>
  <div>772</div>
  <div>773</div>
  <div>774</div>
  <div>775</div>
  <div>776</div>
  <div>777</div>
  <div>778</div>
  <div>779</div>
  <div>780</div>
  <div>781</div>
  <div>782</div>
  <div>783</div>
  <div>784</div>
  <div>785</div>
  <div>786</div>
  <div>787</div>
  <div>788</div>
  <div>789</div>
  <div>790</div>
  <div>791</div>
  <div>792</div>
  <div>793</div>
  <div>794</div>
  <div>795</div>
  <div>796</div>
  <div>797</div>
  <div>798</div>
  <div>799</div>
  <div>800</div>
  <div>801</div>
  <div>802</div>
  <div>803</div>
  <div>804</div>
  <div>805</div>
  <div>806</div>
  <div>807</div>
  <div>808</div>
  <div>809</div>
  <div>810</div>
  <div>811</div>
  <div>812</div>
  <div>813</div>
  <div>814</div>
  <div>815</div>
  <div>816</div>
  <div>817</div>
  <div>818</div>
  <div>819</div>
  <div>820</div>
  <div>821</div>
  <div>822</div>
  <div>823</div>
  <div>824</div>
  <div>825</div>
  <div>826</div>
  <div>827</div>
  <div>828</div>
  <div>829</div>
  <div>830</div>
  <div>831</div>
  <div>832</div>
  <div>833</div>
  <div>834</div>
  <div>835</div>
  <div>836</div>
  <div>837</div>
  <div>838</div>
  <div>839</div>
  <div>840</div>
  <div>841</div>
  <div>842</div>
  <div>843</div>
  <div>844</div>
  <div>845</div>
  <div>846</div>
  <div>847</div>
  <div>848</div>
  <div>849</div>
  <div>850</div>
  <div>851</div>
  <div>852</div>
  <div>853</div>
  <div>854</div>
  <div>855</div>
  <div>856</div>
  <div>857</div>
  <div>858</div>
  <div>859</div>
  <div>860</div>
  <div>861</div>
  <div>862</div>
  <div>863</div>
  <div>864</div>
  <div>865</div>
  <div>866</div>
  <div>867</div>
  <div>868</div>
  <div>869</div>
  <div>870</div>
  <div>871</div>
  <div>872</div>
  <div>873</div>
  <div>874</div>
  <div>875</div>
  <div>876</div>
  <div>877</div>
  <div>878</div>
  <div>879</div>
  <div>880</div>
  <div>881</div>
  <div>882</div>
  <div>883</div>
  <div>884</div>
  <div>885</div>
  <div>886</div>
  <div>887</div>
  <div>888</div>
  <div>889</div>
  <div>890</div>
  <div>891</div>
  <div>892</div>
  <div>893</div>
  <div>894</div>
  <div>895</div>
  <div>896</div>
  <div>897</div>
  <div>898</div>
  <div>899</div>
  <div>900</div>
  <div>901</div>
  <div>902</div>
  <div>903</div>
  <div>904</div>
  <div>905</div>
  <div>906</div>
  <div>907</div>
  <div>908</div>
  <div>909</div>
  <div>910</div>
  <div>911</div>
  <div>912</div>
  <div>913</div>
  <div>914</div>
  <div>915</div>
  <div>916</div>
  <div>917</div>
  <div>918</div>
  <div>919</div>
  <div>920</div>
  <div>921</div>
  <div>922</div>
  <div>923</div>
  <div>924</div>
  <div>925</div>
  <div>926</div>
  <div>927</div>
  <div>928</div>
  <div>929</div>
  <div>930</div>
  <div>931</div>
  <div>932</div>
  <div>933</div>
  <div>934</div>
  <div>935</div>
  <div>936</div>
  <div>937</div>
  <div>938</div>
  <div>939</div>
  <div>940</div>
  <div>941</div>
  <div>942</div>
  <div>943</div>
  <div>944</div>
  <div>945</div>
  <div>946</div>
  <div>947</div>
  <div>948</div>
  <div>949</div>
  <div>950</div>
  <div>951</div>
  <div>952</div>
  <div>953</div>
  <div>954</div>
  <div>955</div>
  <div>956</div>
  <div>957</div>
  <div>958</div>
  <div>959</div>
  <div>960</div>
  <div>961</div>
  <div>962</div>
  <div>963</div>
  <div>964</div>
  <div>965</div>
  <div>966</div>
  <div>967</div>
  <div>968</div>
  <div>969</div>
  <div>970</div>
  <div>971</div>
  <div>972</div>
  <div>973</div>
  <div>974</div>
  <div>975</div>
  <div>976</div>
  <div>977</div>
  <div>978</div>
  <div>979</div>
  <div>980</div>
  <div>981</div>
  <div>982</div>
  <div>983</div>
  <div>984</div>
  <div>985</div>
  <div>986</div>
  <div>987</div>
  <div>988</div>
  <div>989</div>
  <div>990</div>
  <div>991</div>
  <div>992</div>
  <div>993</div>
  <div>994</div>
  <div>995</div>
  <div>996</div>
  <div>997</div>
  <div>998</div>
  <div>999</div>
  <div>1000</div>
  <div>1001</div>
  <div>1002</div>
  <div>1003</div>
  <div>1004</div>
  <div>1005</div>
  <div>1006</div>
  <div>1007</div>
  <div>1008</div>
  <div>1009</div>
  <div>1010</div>
  <div>1011</div>
  <div>1012</div>
  <div>1013</div>
  <div>1014</div>
  <div>1015</div>
  <div>1016</div>
  <div>1017</div>
  <div>1018</div>
  <div>1019</div>
  <div>1020</div>
  <div>1021</div>
  <div>1022</div>
  <div>1023</div>
  <div>1024</div>
  <div>1025</div>
  <div>1026</div>
  <div>1027</div>
  <div>1028</div>
  <div>1029</div>
  <div>1030</div>
  <div>1031</div>
  <div>1032</div>
  <div>1033</div>
  <div>1034</div>
  <div>1035</div>
  <div>1036</div>
  <div>1037</div>
  <div>1038</div>
  <div>1039</div>
  <div>1040</div>
  <div>1041</div>
  <div>1042</div>
  <div>1043</div>
  <div>1044</div>
  <div>1045</div>
  <div>1046</div>
  <div>1047</div>
  <div>1048</div>
  <div>1049</div>
</div>
```

I know it is possible with `display:flex;` but i would like to use grid as i use it in some form of table format.

Comment: That's actually hilarious. Firefox has no problem formatting all rows.

Comment: Found an earlier question on this subject. There's documentation cited there.